# How to include an attribute of a foreign key in the Django Admin 'Add' page?

Tags: python, django

I have two following models:

**models.py:**

```
class Coordinates(models.Model):
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=5, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=5, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"(lat: {self.lat}, lng:{self.lng})"
```

```
class Event(models.Model):
    //other attributes

    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    coordinates =  models.ForeignKey(Coordinates, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="event_coordinates")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.type} by {self.creator}. {self.number_of_people}/{self.people_needed}."
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Event)
```

What I need to do to show 'lat' and 'lng' fields from **cooridinates** inside Admin Add page?

[image: photo]

Comment: I think if you work with a database with GIS support, you can work with a `PointField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield

Comment: Have you created any Coordinates objects in the admin yet? If there aren't any maybe it just has nothing to search for

Comment: I know that will work, but I want to create a new Coordinates object here in Add Event panel. That's why I want to display 'lat' and 'lng' inputs instead of this Select Coordinates form.